# NGINX Reverse Proxy Multiple Domains

Tags: linux, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, raspberry-pi2

Maybe this question got already answered but I can't find the solution for my problem resp. no solution worked for me.

I'm pretty new with NGINX and I've now set up a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B as a Reverse Proxy with NGINX in our company-network. RPi OS is Raspbian v7.
The Hostname (raspberry) of this Reverse Proxy is set over our DHCP Server with a reserved IP.

At the moment I'm able to access another internal Server (resp. its webpage) when I enter the URL for my raspberry  in my webbrowser - this works fine.

nginx.conf configuration - working server block in http block:

```
        server {
            listen 80 default_server;
            server_name webpage;

            location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass <link for mentioned webpage>;
            }
    }
```

Now I would like to be able to access other public/internal websites by entering URLs like:

- raspberry/stackoverflow (proxies to stackoverflow)
- raspberry/google (proxies to google)
- raspberry/facebook (proxies to facebook)

in my webbrowser.

I've tried to use different location blocks in nginx.conf like:

```
        server {
            listen 80 default_server;

            location /webpage {
               proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
               proxy_set_header Host $host;
               proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
               proxy_pass <link for mentioned webpage>;
            }

            location /stackoverflow {
               proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
               proxy_set_header Host $host;
               proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
               proxy_pass <link-stackoverflow>;
            }

            location /google{
               proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
               proxy_set_header Host $host;
               proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
               proxy_pass <link-google>;
            }

            #and so on.....

        }
```

But this doesn't work, if I enter raspberry/google I get a 404 error from google:

```
The requested URL /google was not found on this server
```

This means it searches for https://www.google.com/google instead of just https://www.google.com/

How could I realise my plan? Any help is greatly appreciated :)

P.S. Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to post more than 2 links yet so I wasn't able to write real links (see <>).

Comment: A trailing slash on both the `location` and `proxy_pass` directives will cause `nginx` to rewrite the URI. See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks for your answer but what if i don't what to proxie in a specific directory like  https://www.google.com/google but https://www.google.com

Comment: It works now for me! Just deleted every line in per location block except the proxy_pass directive.

Comment: Nevertheless it doesn't really work. I get various errors with this configuration. For some websites the CSS or even the whole page doesn't load and if I click on links of proxied websites I get 404 Errors. @RichardSmith